# start getty on variable serial console

Tags: linux, serial-port, kernel, tty, uart

I have two serial port on my embedded board ttyS2 and ttyS3,I want to start getty on configured serial port (ttyS2/ttyS3),I'm passing `console=ttyS3,115200` and `console=ttyS2,115200` as console in kernel boot parameter.

I'm starting getty using following command in /etc/inittab

```
/sbin/getty -L ttyS2 115200 vt100 -H HOME -u root -a
/sbin/getty -L ttyS3 115200 vt100 -H HOME -u root -a
```

How can I start getty for serial port which was passed in kernel boot parameter (/proc/cmdline) in /etc/inittab?

Comment: I think `/sbin/getty -L console 115200 vt100 -H HOME -u root -a` should work

Comment: [Systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) seems to handle the kernel console automatically. See this [blog](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html).